# PYTHON file open using list

Tags: python, list, file

```
file_1=open("file.txt")
lis=[]
for i in file_1:
    lis=i
    print(lis)
print(lis)
```

I want to keep my text file into the list, but after for loop the list becomes empty

Comment: `lis=i` overwrites the list `lis` with the string of the line. You want `lis.append(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

The comment posted explains the issue with the code. However, python has a built-in function for this purpose:

```
file_1=open("file.txt")
lis = file_1.readlines()
```